# Secant Method in Python

Tags: python, math, iteration

This is my code on secant method:

```py
#initialization for x0, x1, n
raw_input1 = input("Please enter an integer:\n")
raw_input2 = input("Please enter an integer:\n")
raw_input3 = input("Please enter an integer:\n")
x0 = int(raw_input1)
x1 = int(raw_input2)
n  = int(raw_input3)
print(f'You entered {x0} as x0 & {x1} as x0')
print(f'You entered {n} as n for iteration number')


#coeffecients 
G = 6.674*(10**-11) ; M = 5.974*(10**24) ; m = 7.348*(10**22) ; R= 7.348*(10**22) ; w = 2.662*(10**-6)

#secant function
def secant(x0,x1,n):
    for i in range(n):
        if f(x1)-f(x0) == 0:
            return x1
        else:
            r = ((x1-((f(x1)*(x1-x0))))/(f(x1)-f(x0)))*1.0
            x0 = x1
            x1 = r
    return x1


#f(r) function
def f(r) :                      
    return r+((G*M)/((R**2)-(r**2))*(w**2))-((G*M)/(R**2)*(w**2))
```

There seems to be no syntax error but I think I haven't written it properly as it doesn't give me any answers. Would be nice if anyone can help with the error and tell me what I did wrong and how I can solve this.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't give me any answers"? What answer do you expect to get? How do you use this code? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I will fix the indentation. Like i said, there isnt any error messages. I personally believe I didnt loop it properly.

Comment: There are already good pythonic implementation out for *Secant Method* to find real root of nonlinear equation. Please check [here](https://www.codesansar.com/numerical-methods/secant-method-python-program.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the complete code? If so, then you are not 'getting any answers' because you have not run any functions yet. All your code does is get an input and define two functions. If you want secant to actually run, you need to call it. Just add the line:

```
secant(x0,x1,n)
```

But first make sure you give x1 a value.

Comment: in my actual code it is that way, so the indentation isnt wrong.

Comment: @HiIsuckatcoding I updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.